# Mazda 3 SP leaking coolant

Tags: cooling-system

I have a Mazda 3 SP 23 2005 _ manual _ 2.0 Liter unleaded.

I have noticed that some cooling liquid started leaking on my parking spot a week ago. The leaking stains are becoming bigger day after day. It's mostly coming from the right side when you are facing the engine. I had a quick chat with one mechanic which believes it could be coming from the thermostat. He told me to refill the cooling liquid tank with some water before I fix the problem. 
Does anyone have any idea what the leak could come from?
I don't know anything about cars, I want to resolve the problems ASAP but I don't want to be ripped off.
Thank you in advance for your help
Regards
Sylvain

Comment: Please fix your title... ie caps...

Answer (score 1):

A leak can come from many things, you can have a bad seal, a loose hose, a hole in a hose, or a hole in your radiator. The thermostat is one possibility - there's a seal on it which may have blown, if that's the case then it's probably pretty cheap to fix. The only way to know for sure is to track it down by getting  under the car.

Unless the radiator itself has developed a leak I wouldn't expect this repair to cost too much.

Comment: Thank you for your advice. I have an appointment with another mechanic on Wednesday . I will keep you posted